# Firebase: How to send push notifications in batches to avoid problem with backend overload?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an app (iOS, Android) where we send push notifications to from the Firebase web interface to all the registered users.

The backend system cannot handle the peak load that occurs when all the users are pulled into the app calling the REST API from the push notifications.

Is there a way to split the registered users to send the push notifications little by little at an appropriate rate?

I suspect that this has to be done programmatically. C#?

[Question with workarounds handling peak times when sending push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243818/scaling-issue-while-sending-push-notifications-in-bulk-to-all-the-devices-subs)

Answer (score 2):

The web console for sending notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging does not have a way to throttle message delivery. It's an interesting concern though, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

For the moment though, I can think of two options:

1. Create multiple audiences that cover your entire user base, and then send to each audience at a different time.
2. Use the FCM API to send out the messages to your users in batches.